# How do I filter this python defaultdict on a value within a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a defaultdict, python 3.4, object similar to:

```
mydefaultdict = defaultdict(dict)
mydefaultdict['name1']['filename'] = 'name1'
mydefaultdict['name1']['records_available'] = True
mydefaultdict['name2']['filename'] = 'name2'
mydefaultdict['name2']['records_available'] = False
```

I want to create a filtered subset of just those with `records_available = True`. So far I have a dict comprehension that does:

```
defaultdict(dict, {k: v['records_available'] for k, v 
               in mydefaultdict.items() })
```

which is really close. But I'm not sure how to implement a filter. If this were a basic dict something like the following would work.

```py
defaultdict(dict, {k: v['records_available'] for k, v 
               in mydefaultdict.items() if v == True })
```

I've managed to accomplish this using a nested `for, if` loop. But I got so close with the dict comprehension I wonder if someone might have the solution. Parsing python collections is a daily activity for me.

My current solution:

```py
for i in audio_files.values():
    if i['records_available']:
        filterd_files[i['filename']] = i
```

Edit:
user3100115 is correct. Mock problem data will no return one record with user31000115's response.

Comment: `{k:v for k, v in mydefaultdict.items() if v['records_available'] == True }`

Comment: @user3100115: why did not you post this as an answer?

Comment: user3100115 it turns out I was very tired and was using precisely the code I pasted above. As you will note my dummy records both are `False`. I actually tried a very similar version of your solution and of course got zero records back. Thanks for both confirming my sanity and making me feel sheepish. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks odd that you want to get `v['records_available']` as the value (for all that this value is true). But what you probably want to look out for is the case where the values does not have the element `'records_available'` or is not a dictionary at all. The former can be solved by using using the `.get` method, but if you want to protect you from the latter you have to define your own `getitem` (similar to `getattr`) that will return `default` when the object either doesn't support subscription at all or doesn't contain the requested item:

```
def getitem(obj, key, default=None):
    try:
        return obj[key]
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
        return default
```

Then you just use this as a filter (I use `func(v)` to transform the value to what value you want since I think going for the `"records_available"` item is pointless - it would only be `True`):

```
{k, func(v) for k, v in mydefaultdict.items() if getitem(v, "records_available") == True)}
```

Note that `getitem` will return `None` whenever `v` doesn't contain `"records_available"` or doesn't support subscription at all - and then consequently that key-value pair will not make it into the dictionary.